# Change Color of Fonts in DIV (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the color and size of H2 font and H2 link fonts based on the div they are in but have not been successful. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <style>
h2 {
color:fff;
font-size: 20px;
}
social.h2 {
color:pink;
font-size: 14px;
}
social.h2.h2color {
color:purple;
font-size: 10px;
}
tv.h2 {
color:green;
font-size: 14px;
}
tv.h2.h2color {
color:orange;
font-size: 10px;
}
 </style>

 <h2>List of Companies </h2>
 <div class="social">

 <h2>     <A href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook     </a>
 <span class="h2color">Found in 2004     </span>     </h2> 
 blah blah blah 

 <h2>     <A href="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter     </a>
 <span class="h2color">Found in 2007     </span>     </h2>
 blah blah blah 

 </div>


 <div class="tv">

 <h2>     <A href="http://www.fox.com">Fox     </a>
 <span class="h2color">Found in 2004     </span>     </h2> 
 blah blah blah 

 <h2>     <A href="http://www.nbc.com">NBC     </a>
 <span class="h2color">Found in 2007     </span>     </h2>
 blah blah blah 
 </div>
```

I am trying to make it look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your first CSS selector—`social.h2`—is looking for the "social" element in the "h2", class, e.g.:

```
<social class="h2">
```

Class selectors are proceeded with a dot (`.`). Also, use a space () to indicate that one element is inside of another. To find an `<h2>` descendant of an element in the `social` class, try something like:

```
.social h2 {
  color: pink;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

To get a better understanding of CSS selectors and how they are used to reference your HTML, I suggest going through the [interactive HTML and CSS tutorials from CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/htmlcss). I hope that this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: sweet, thanks! this worked perfectly for the H2's. is there a way to change the H2 links as well? also it seems like the H2s in the div are relative. So like if I want 14px font it comes up smaller than it should

Comment: Mike, try a selector like: `.social h2 a` for styling your link (`<a>`) elements.

Answer (score 8):

To do links, you can do

```
.social h2 a:link {
  color: pink;
  font-size: 14px;   
}
```

You can change the hover, visited, and active link styling too. Just replace "link" with what you want to style. You can learn more at the w3schools page [CSS Links](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp).